# Autolayout in storyboard, how do I set a width of a subview to be 1/3 of it's superview?

Tags: storyboard, autolayout

I know this might be pretty straight forward, but, I am trying to figure out how to tell a subview that its width needs to be 1/3 of the width of its superview. I want to do this in STORYBOARD, not in code. So the situation is super simple, just a UIView inside of a ViewController's view.

How can I accomplish this using Autolayout in storyboard?

Answer (score 7):

First, in the storyboard view tree, ctrl-drag from the subview to its container and select "equal widths":

[image: Set equal widths]

Then, open the width constraint in the inspector on the right, and change "Multiplier" to 1/3:

[image: Change multiplier to 1/3]