# Using Auto Layout, give an object a dynamic size based on the screen size

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, autolayout, constraints

In my Xcode Storyboard, I have an Image View, and I have a large image in it. Let's say I set it to 500 pixels by 500 pixels.

Yet, I don't want it to be too large on small screens, and screens in both landscape and portrait. So how can I get it to shrink to fit on small screens, yet still expand up to 500x500 on larger screens?

Comment: With the tags on question.Autolayout and constraints.

Comment: are you working on landscape and portrait mode?

Comment: Both landscape and portrait.

Answer (score 0):

You can [set childView's width a percentage of the superView in storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534861/autolayout-in-storyboard-how-do-i-set-a-width-of-a-subview-to-be-1-3-of-its-su)(maybe set multiplier 500:768 is right for you). [Also there is  a blog about that](http://simblestudios.com/blog/development/easier-percentage-width-in-autolayout.html).

Answer (score -2):

You can get a reference with your superview and adjust your image frame.

```
@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let width = self.view.frame.width / 3  // Use your own ratio
    image.frame.size = CGSizeMake(width,width)
}
```

for autolayouts get references for width and height constraints.

```
@IBOutlet weak var widthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let width = self.view.frame.width/3   // Use your own ratio

    widthConstraint.constant = width
    heightConstraint.constant = widht
}
```

-– depending on the view size you can adjust your image size.